# Cygwin on Windows 7 died waiting for dll loading

Tags: windows, dll, cygwin

I have been getting the infamous "died waiting for dll loading; no child processes" error on my Cygwin installation (64-bit) on Windows 7. It all started when I attempted to install an update to Cygwin. I haven't installed any other software on the Windows 7 machine, so I don't believe that there is a conflict.

I have read the various entries about running `rebaseall`, which I have run, and that hasn't helped. I did see one post where someone said that they had figured out what to do when `rebaseall` doesn't work. But, the link in their post that pointed to the hinted at solution was dead.

I have tried removing the `/etc/rebase.db.x86_64` file and running the `rebaseall` again.

I have tried removing my `C:\cygwin64 directory and C:\cygwinInstall` (that's where I have it put the downloaded files) and completely reinstalling, but that hasn't worked either.

I also tried loading the 32-bit version of Cygwin. That installation cannot even run the `rebaseall` command (it gets the fork error).

I am hoping that someone can provide another option for me to try.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue on Windows 7 Enterprise (SP1), with Cygwin 32-bit installation. After switching to cygwin 64-bit, as suggested @ https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures
, I could use cygwin now.